# Passing a Shiny input to R markdown via Shiny Server

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, shiny-server, sweave

I am trying to build a Shiny App and host it on my company's Shiny server that takes an inputted stock code and uses it to pull data from our database and generate a series of graphs and tables in markdown(.md) or word(.doc) format. Ideally, I would have three files for this App: server, ui, and the r markdown template.

I currently have a working App that uses SWeave, but TeX files have issues rendering Chinese characters, so I would like to use RMD.

**server.r:**

```
library(knitr)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
 output$report = downloadHandler(
      filename = 'myreport.pdf',
      content = function(file) {
           out = knit2pdf('input.Rnw', clean = TRUE)
           file.rename(out, file) # move pdf to file for downloading
      },
      contentType = 'application/pdf'
 )
})
```

**ui.r:**

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(basicPage(
 textInput('stockcode', 'Stock Code:', value = '600340.SH'),
 downloadButton('report')
))
```

**input.Rnw:**

```
 \documentclass{article}

 \begin{document}
 \SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

 <<initialize, echo = FALSE, results = 'hide'>>=
 library(ggplot2); library(RJDBC); library(gridExtra)
 Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "chinese")
 o.drv <- JDBC("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver", classPath="C:/Oracle/instantclient_11_2/ojdbc5.jar", " ")
 o.con <- dbConnect(o.drv, "database_address", "database_user", "database_pw")

 stockcode <- input$stockcode

 x <- dbGetQuery(o.con, "some_query")

 pointLinePlot <- function(df) {
      plotdata <- gather(df, metric, measure, -reportDate)
      ggplot() + geom_line(data = plotdata, aes(x = reportDate, y = measure, color = metric)) +
           geom_point(data = plotdata, aes(x = reportDate, y = measure, color = metric)) + 
           theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.title = element_blank()) + 
           scale_color_manual(name = "", values = c("darkred", "darkgreen", "darkblue", "orange"), 
                              breaks = unique(plotdata$metric), labels = unique(plotdata$metric))
 }

 data_1.1.1 <- data.frame(reportDate = x$REPORT_PERIOD,
                          net_assets_f = x$`TOT_ASSETS-TOT_LIAB` / 1E4,
                          monetary_cap_f = x$MONETARY_CAP / 1E4,
                          net_cash_f = (x$MONETARY_CAP - x$ST_BORROW) / 1E4)
 p1 <- pointLinePlot(data_1.1.1)
 @


 \begin{figure}
   \centering
 <<fig = TRUE, echo = FALSE>>=
 print(p1)
 @
 \caption{Here goes the caption.}
 \label{fig:p1}
 \end{figure}


 \begin{figure}
   \centering
 <<fig = TRUE, echo = FALSE>>=
 print(grid.table(data_1.1.1, rows = NULL))
 @
 \caption{Here goes the caption.}
 \label{fig:p1}
 \end{figure}


 \end{document}
```

Is there any way to pass the an input from a Shiny App directly to RMD like I have in input.Rnw with SWeave (stockcode <- input$stockcode)?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to pass it to the Rmd file. When the Rmd is rendered, the variable `input$stockcode` is taken from the current environment just like it was with the Rnw version.

**server.R**

```
library(knitr)
library(rmarkdown)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$report = downloadHandler(
    filename = 'myreport.pdf',
    content = function(file) {
      out = render('outout.Rmd')
      file.rename(out, file) # move pdf to file for downloading
    },
    contentType = NA
  )
})
```

**input.Rmd**

````
---
title: "Output"
output: pdf_document
---

# Test 

```{r}
print(input$stockcode)
```
````

[image]